# Font setup in header (ConTeXt)

Tags: formatting, header-footer, context

I use `\setupheadertexts    [][section][chapter][]` to get the section- and chapter-title in the header of the odd- and even pages. How to change the font, like its size, or making it bold or italic? The way `\setupheadertexts  [][\it section][chapter][]` does not work, as "section" is than interpreted as text, and not as variable.

Comment: Now there is [some info about styles](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Style_Alternatives) on the wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using an explicit font switch in `\setupheadertexts` it is better to set the style of the header (or other page markup areas like footer, top, and bottom) using `\setupheader`. If you want to change the style of all header elements use

```
\setupheader[style=italic]
```

If you want to use separate styles for left and right header, use

```
\setupheader[leftstyle=italic, rightstyle=bold]
```

Of course, like all setup commands that accept `style` key, you can use the `color` (and `leftcolor` and `rightcolor`) key to set the color as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\getmarking[section]` instead. Since you
use brackets inside brackets, you have to wrap it in an extra pair
of braces.

```
\setupheadertexts
  [] [{\italic\getmarking[section]}]
  [{\italic\getmarking[chapter]}][]
```

More information in the [manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf)
in the section about “Marking”.

Comment: Thanks. And how to change the size, like `\tiny{}` in LaTeX, I searched the manual for that briefly, but did not found the equivalent command.

Comment: [Wiki - Font Switching](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching)