# How to change the font of header?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize

When I am typing in latex, I find that the name of the chapter is too long. In order to avoid the header getting too crowded (as shown), 
[image: header overfull]

I intend to reduce the font size of the header, but I do not know how to do that. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Lecture Notes}
\author{Terry}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%I wonder what I can put here to reduce the size of the headers for chapter name
\mainmatter
\chapter{Cauchy's Integral Formula and Consequences}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you can use the optional argument of `\chapter` by typing `\chapter[short title]{very very very long title}` so only short title appear in header.

Comment: @touhami Thank you for your suggestion, but I still prefer to reduce the font size of the header, if that is possible.

Comment: @Hupfer I'm sorry that I do not know this. It is the first time for me to post a question here. Anyway, I have posted an example and I hope that helps.

Comment: Use package fancyhdr. See its documentation.

Comment: For ConTeXt, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77963/font-setup-in-header-context

Answer (score 8):

You have two main options. Starting with the simpler one:

1. Use the `\chapter[short title]{long title}` device.

   E.g., in your case, you might write

   ```
   \chapter[Cauchy's Integral Formula]{Cauchy's Integral Formula and Consequences}
   ```

   I've noticed that you've commented that you would prefer not use use this device and, instead, to reduce the running header's font size. Nevertheless, I think you should give it some serious thought. Especially if you have very long chapter titles, if you don't use the short-title device you may need to reduce the font size so drastically (in order to make the title fit in the running header) that the material will become undecipherable -- unless you provide magnifying glasses with each book you sell.
2. Load a package that makes it straightforward to customize the headers and footers; among these packages are `fancyhdr`, `titleps` and `scrlayer-scrpage`. For instance, if you were to work with the `fancyhdr` package, you might write

   ```
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\thepage}
   \fancyhead[RE]{\footnotesize\slshape\leftmark}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   ```

   Why `\footnotesize`? Assuming "Cauchy's Integral Formula and Consequences" is a representative-length chapter name, and assuming you're using standard page block parameters, using `\small` wouldn't be enough to fit the whole string comfortably on one line.

Comment: Can you please change your second item, to load a package that deals with header/footer customization? `fancyhdr` is one of them, others could be `titleps` and `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Unfortunately, i cannot upvote again ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works perfectly well! I have tried using `fancyhdr` before, but it will show both the chapter name and the section name, which makes it even worse. I wonder why here your code does not change it.

Comment: @Terry - I'm not sure I understand the gist of your follow-up query, "I wonder why your code does not change it." What does the particle "it" refer to?

Comment: I mean the default format of `fancyhdr` is that the chapter name is written on the right and the section name is written on the left, which is different from the format of the header without this `fancyhdr` package. However, when I compile your code, no section name appears in the header, and I wonder what part of your code changes this default format.

Comment: Never mind. I get it. I just got confused with some codes in `fancyhdr`, but I am clear now. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Terry - Clearly, `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and `\pagestyle{fancy}` simply switch the page style from "plain" (the default) to "fancy". The most important instruction may be `\fancyhead{}`, as it wipes out the "standard fancy" header setup (which features both the current chapter title and the current section title). The remaining instructions just tell LaTeX what material *should* be shown.

Comment: Wow, the 7th upvote on this answer lifted my reputation point total above the 200K mark! Thanks so much!! And thanks to the entire community on TeX.SE!!